# New Android studio 2.1.3 install on 32 bit ubuntu having "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" issues

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, gradle

I just installed Android studio about a day ago on my new Ubuntu 32 bit OS and after setting up the SDK and all, it keeps showing 'cannot resolve symbol R' and could not build the application as ADB wasn't working.
I have checked a bunch of resources online and I took the advise I saw there and dropped my platform-tools and build-tools to version 23.0.1. Now, ADB works but I still get the 'cannot resolve symbol R problem".
Although this is not really concerned with the title, but I created a new project and it has been running gradle build for hours. I imported a project from a github repository and it builds that quite fast. That's where it all gets confusing.

Please, what should I do to get my Android studio working fine?

Comment: For now, I seem to have neutralized the issue. I had to drop my compile version to 23 being Marshmallow and so it goes with build-tools and platform-tools that are the 23.0.1 variant. All issues seem resolved and gradle built in less than a minute.

Comment: Please add some more information, for example, what your code looks like and which version of ubuntu your using.